# Second dropdown value is not changing if I doesn't change my first dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to show a table of reviews by taking the value of two dropdowns. When I was having one dropdown(positive, negative etc) that works fine but when I introduce another dropdown(food, drinks etc) it is not working.
It only works when I change the first dropdown and second dropdown but if I kept the first dropdown unchanged then it's not working

I tried by adding onchange method to the second dropdown. I just started with Javascript so not much idea about what to try.

```js
function printResult(form) {
  var output = {
    {
      output | safe
    }
  };
  var sel = form.list;
  var sel2 = form.list2;
  var selectedVal = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
  var selectedVal2 = sel2.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
  //document.getElementById("showResult").innerText = "Your number is: " + selectedVal;
  //console.log(output);
  document.getElementById("showResult").innerText = "Your number is: " + selectedVal2;
}
```

```html
<form action="dropdown" onSubmit="return printResult(this);">
  <label for="sentiment">Sentiment</label>
  <div class="styled-select blue semi-square">
    <select name="list">
      <option value="all">All</option>
      <option value="positive">Positive</option>
      <option value="negative">Negative</option>
      <option value="neutral">Neutral</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select name="list2" onChange="printResult()">
      <option value="menu">Menu Range</option>
      <option value="food">Food</option>
      <option value="drinks">Drinks</option>
      <option value="desserts">Desserts</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Filter">
  <span id="showResult"></span>
</form>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. It gives console warnings so fix those first. Then remember to preventDefault or return false in the function

Comment: `output | safe`  is not valid object content

Comment: output | safe is actually from django. From django's views it has passed which contains the array of reviews, sentiment and topic.

Comment: There was no Django tag so I could not know that

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, that was just an array of arrays in javascript when I passed. Forget about that output part I actually want to get the values of those two dropdowns after hitting the filter button whether I change or not change. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the form on the change too and return false to not submit the form:

```js
function printResult(form) {
  var sel = form.list;
  var sel2 = form.list2;
  var selectedVal = sel.value;
  var selectedVal2 = sel2.value;
  document.getElementById("showResult").innerText = "Your number is: " + selectedVal2;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form action="dropdown" onSubmit="return printResult(this);">
  <label for="sentiment">Sentiment</label>
  <div class="styled-select blue semi-square">
    <select name="list">
      <option value="all">All</option>
      <option value="positive">Positive</option>
      <option value="negative">Negative</option>
      <option value="neutral">Neutral</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select name="list2" onChange="printResult(this.form)">
      <option value="menu">Menu Range</option>
      <option value="food">Food</option>
      <option value="drinks">Drinks</option>
      <option value="desserts">Desserts</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Filter">
  <span id="showResult"></span>
</form>
```

Perhaps you wanted this instead

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("form1").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
    var sel = this.list;
    var sel2 = this.list2;
    var selectedVal = sel.value;
    var selectedVal2 = sel2.value;
    document.getElementById("showResult").innerText = (selectedVal && selectedVal2) ? selectedVal + ":" + selectedVal2 : "Please select both";
  });
});
```

```html
<form action="dropdown" id="form1">
  <label for="sentiment">Sentiment</label>
  <div class="styled-select blue semi-square">
    <select name="list">
      <option value="">All</option>
      <option value="positive">Positive</option>
      <option value="negative">Negative</option>
      <option value="neutral">Neutral</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <select name="list2">
      <option value="">Menu Range</option>
      <option value="food">Food</option>
      <option value="drinks">Drinks</option>
      <option value="desserts">Desserts</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Filter">
  <span id="showResult"></span>
</form>
```

Comment: Instead of onChange can I do onSubmit. Because I want like this >  

Sentiment: Choose something(positive, negative, neutral)  
Second dropdown: Choose something(food, menu, drinks etc)  

Then accordingly it will show result.

Comment: See second example

Comment: Thanks alot.You saved a ton of time of me. It worked as I want.